# Error while installing Eclipse in MAC (Can this issue be effect that I am using company laptop)

Tags: java

```
> This is the Error below
>[2022-07-01 18:41:02] Repository https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022->06/202206151000
```

> [2022-07-01 18:41:02] Repository >https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
> [2022-07-01 18:41:03] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to >read repository at [https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2022->06/202206091200/content.xml](https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2022-%3E06/202206091200/content.xml).
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: >sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid >certification path to requested target
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
> at >java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(U>nknown Source)
> at >java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertifica>te(Unknown Source)
> at >java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown >Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
> at >org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnec>tionSocketFactory.java:273)
> at >org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSo>cketFactory.java:241)
> at >org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultH>ttpClientConnectionOperator.java:148)

Comment: When I go access this URL in my browser https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-%3E06/202206151000 

It is not found.

Comment: That link is bad.  Take a look at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ and download the correct version for your machine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` exception looks to be related to the self-assigned certificate

Comment: also it is possible the firewall software on your company laptop is blocking the connections.